# Parsing from a string or ComboBox Value to Enum

Tags: c#, combobox, enums

So i got a project to build a library like program.
a program where i have a few items like Books, Magazines and other stuff that exist in a library. in the program i can add new items, delete items, view the inventory just like a real library.

i work with C# WINRT WIN8.1.
in the 'AddItem' window i have couple of TextBoxes from there i can get the user to add the item title, Published Year of the item, Author name etc.
but when i get to the Genre Part (which i created with Enum) the parsing wont work.
i tried working with comboBox with the Enum as the ItemsSource.
and i tried with TextBox and just let the user wright by himself  the Genre.

this is the code in the Button Where i click to add the item to the List of items in the library:

```
private void btnEnterItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if the selected item in the comboBox is: Book
        //put all the relevant information in the book class/book list(add new book)
        //same thing if the selected item is journal or magazine
        if (typeCbox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Book")
        {

            //Enum.TryParse<Genres>(genreCbok.SelectedValue.ToString(), out Genres);
            libMng.List.Add(new Book(tBlkItemTitle.Text, tBlkItemAuthor.Text, Enum.Parse(typeof(Genres) ,tBoxGenre.Text), Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Parse(tBlkItemYear.Text), true));
        }
```

*i have a class of BOOK, Magazine, Journal which all inherit from AbstractItem.
in the AbstractItem class i have a constructor that have all the items properties like: Title, PublishedYear, Guid etc.

can you help me to understand which is the best way to get the user to select a genre and how do i parse it to be able to add the item to the list?

Comment: Do you get an exception? Or what exactly isn't working?

Comment: its says:" Cannot convert from 'object' to 'LibraryProject.Library.models.Genres' "

Comment: I guess your enum is called Genres and you entered the name of the enum? Did you check wether the `tboxGenre.Text` property is of type string? And could you provide the header of the `Book` constructor?

Comment: Well i guess it's a type string because one way i tried was to let the user wright the name of the genre himself, like, Adventure, Fantasy etc.

and by header of the 'Book' Constructor i guess you mean that:


" public Book(string type, string title, string author, Genres genre, Guid isbn, DateTime year, bool isInStock) : base(type, title, genre, isbn, year, isInStock)
        {
            Author = author;
        } "